# Can workday call an external webservice?

Tags: workday-api

We are starting to implement workday and had a question regarding whether workday can call an external webservice.

Comment: Workday can call external web services using Workday Studio. Studio allows you to build complex applications and integrations utilizing both Workday Web services as well as external WS or for that matter from any other source, method, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears there is an API.  https://community.workday.com/api

Hereis the web services documentation.
https://community.workday.com/custom/developer/API/index.html

Workday offers an open, standards-based SOAP API for programmatic access to our On-Demand Business Management Services. The following directory provide the API Documentation for our multi-tenant SOAP-based web services with corresponding WSDL and XML Schemas (XSD's).

Comment: The documentation says only webservices made available by workday and how a client can call those workday exposed services. It doesnt mention how workday can call an external webservice be it thru EIB or Workday studio. Thanks.

Comment: Look at.  https://community.workday.com/custom/developer/API/index.html   The External Integrations Web Service provides an operation that informs external systems of Integration Events that have been triggered from within Workday. The WSDL for this service provides the structure that needs to be implemented by an external system to receive event "Launch" information.

Comment: I would say that the External Integrations webservice does not allow Workday to call external webservices and therefore the answer ought to be 'No', but the question is, what does the OP want to accomplish with such an external webservice, because there are almost certainly ways to do it without Workday calling an external webservice.

Answer (score 2):

Workday definitely can call external web services. Workday offers an integration platform with an Eclipse based IDE. It is a full ESB platform that can call http(s) SOAP and REST services. There are complex orchestrations with flow control and transformations. It is an extremely powerful integration platform that some of the world's largest firms use to integrate with third party systems.

The api's described previously are for inbound data flows from external systems.

Answer (score 2):

Workday allows outbound calls using their "outbound subscription" service.

This integration pattern is described here:
https://community.boomi.com/docs/DOC-2614#jive_content_id_Outbound_Subscriptions

A more reliable integration pattern is to use message queuing:
https://community.boomi.com/docs/DOC-2614#jive_content_id_Message_Queuing

Answer (score 1):

How should the external web device call be triggered?

I believe doing a soap or restful web service call from a Studio solution would be relatively simple .... As long as workday does not limit outgoing connections from a studio integration.

There are some security limits on what what an integration can do - such as they are not allowed to read local files (on the workday host) using Java IO routines , etc